# Extract certain words from sentences using natural language processing

Tags: java, twitter, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm new to natural language processing. I'm working on a project that extracts what users feel analyzing on what they tweets.

Example:

'I’m so **tired** of not being a multimillionaire' :  User feels tired.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this and what kind of API or library (Java) can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are interested in doing belongs to the field in NLP called "sentiment analysis". Now, that you know that, googling for possible libraries and methods should be easier. :)

If you are looking for a java library with instructions on how to do sentiment analysis on tweets here's the first thing I found with fairly detailed instructions:

http://rahular.com/twitter-sentiment-analysis/

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your help